# Failed to fetch Flask Web Service on EC2 : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, fetch-api

I am trying to create a simple Flask web service on EC2 as an internal network API. When I run the Flask app, it displays the following message:
"running on [http://127.0.0.1:5000/"](http://127.0.0.1:5000/%22)

I tested it using the curl command:
"curl [http://127.0.0.1:5000/"](http://127.0.0.1:5000/%22)
and it returns: "Hello, world!"

Then, on the same host with the flask app, I created a test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('error:', error);
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then on my windows chrome broswer, I open https://example.com/test.html

The console displayed: "POST https://127.0.0.1:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Can anyone tell me why?

Here is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Are you running Chrome on the EC2 instance, or on your local machine?  If you're running on your local machine, the webpage is trying to connect to your local machine with "127.0.0.1", not the EC2 instance.

Comment: Now that I have clarified the issue, thank you very much for your response.! I can continue working on my university project now.